# paranoia gem restore for has one dependent destroy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, acts-as-paranoid

I am using

```
Paranoia gem(3.1.1)
Rails 3.2
```

I've noticed that the `has_one :model, dependent: :destroy` is not being restored.

Let's say..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

If I do..

```
@user.destroy
User.restore(@user.id, recursive: true)
```

user and its posts will be restored but not the profile.

Is there any thing I can do to make it work?

By the way, I am using a forked version of Paranoia because I cannot get this version https://github.com/radar/paranoia/blob/rails3/lib/paranoia.rb#L105